# Changing tab text color on selection

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-material2

I am working on Angular4 and have been using angular material.  I have created a tab-group and I want to change the text color of a tab label when I select any tab. I have tried to override the default css but that didn't help me.

I can override the ink bar but I am not able to override tab-text color upon selection

```
.mat-ink-bar{
    background-color:#00ADEE;
}
 /*.mat-tab-label::selection{
 color: #00ADEE !important;
 } */
```

The commented part which I was trying to change the color of a tab-label-color.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to use the following class for active tab:

```
.mat-tab-label-active {
     color: #00ADEE !important;
 }
```

Here is a link to [working demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-h6pugw?file=app%2Fapp.component.css).

Answer (score 0):

```
.mat-tab-label-active .mat-tab-label-content {
 //your style here
}
```