# How can I add a custom class to an Angular Material tab?

Tags: angular, angular-material2

In Angular 6, I am using Angular Material to display some data using Tabs.

```
<mat-tab-group>
    <mat-tab 
    *ngFor="let bar of foo.bar" 
    [label]="bar.Name"
    [ngClass]="bar.IsActive ? 'bar-on' : 'bar-off'">
      // ...
    </mat-tab>
  </mat-tab-group>
```

I would like to style the tabs differently whether the `IsActive` property of bar is `true` or `false`.

I have tried using `[ngClass]="bar.IsActive ? 'bar-on' : 'bar-off'"` as shown above, but the class is not added.

Out of spite, I have tried the much simpler `class = 'bar-on'` but even then the class is not added.

Therefore, I am wondering, **is it possible to add a custom class to an Angular Material tab?**

Edit: 
The `IsActive` property is a property of `foo` objects. It has nothing to do with  the activated state of the tab. The active tab can display an object with `IsActive = false` and vice-versa.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I'm trying to do the same thing.

Comment: There is an issue for this but it's closed https://github.com/angular/components/issues/9290

Answer (score 16):

Yes its possible by using `ng-template` instead of `label`.

Example of `ngClass` on first tab. [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-9njbdf?file=app%2Ftab-group-basic-example.html)

```
<mat-tab-group>
  <mat-tab > 
   <ng-template mat-tab-label>
                <span [ngClass]="{'color-red': isError?'red':'black'}">Security</span>
   </ng-template>
    Content 1 
   </mat-tab>
  <mat-tab label="Second"> Content 2 </mat-tab>
  <mat-tab label="Third"> Content 3 </mat-tab>
</mat-tab-group>
```

Comment: This only affects a small area inside the label (surrounding the span text), so I cannot set the background-color of the label, but only the background-color of the span :(

Answer (score 3):

Seems like angular was a mess 4+ years ago cuz all the answers here are not applicable today. In 2023 if you want to add some custom classes to the tab trigger itself or to container it is bound to you just use `labelClass` and `bodyClass` respectively, as stated in [docs](https://material.angular.io/components/tabs/api#MatTab)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to modify the active tab, use this:

```
.mat-tab-label-active {
 //your style here
}
```

If you want to modify the label style within the active tab, do this:

```
 .mat-tab-label-active .mat-tab-label-content {
   //your style here
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

**Target the element by attribue to apply style**

```
:host::ng-deep .mat-tab-label[aria-posinset='1']{
    /*apply your css here*/
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems like the `<mat-tab>` element gets removed, so if you want to add a CSS class to it, you can just wrap the tab contents in another div and add the class to that div.

Answer (score 0):

I am using Angular 11 atm, and the label class feature was introduced later, so I have to do it differently.

But generally, with Angular 13+, this should be possible by using the @Input `[labelClass]="my-classname"`.
https://material.angular.io/components/tabs/api

And instead of `::ng-deep`, better use `encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.none`, if you need to style elements from 3rd party imports.

Comment: My first exposure to Angular was in a project with view encapsulation disabled. It is a terrible idea, DO NOT DO IT. It allows any CSS file to style any part of the application, which will likely result in chaos especially if you have already written CSS with the assumption this won't happen.

Comment: Yes, but you "encapsulate" it by yourself in your component.scss with a class surrounding your component content. It is essentials sometimes if you need to style a nested 3rd party component...

Answer (score -1):

Instead of using [ngClass] for highlighting an active tab, you could ..

```
.mat-tab-label-active{
//your code...
}
```

See this :https://stackoverflow.com/a/45962498/5319180

Also :https://github.com/angular/material2/issues/5014

**EDIT**: to get the domain specific info, as you said..maybe this would help?

```
<mat-tab *ngFor="let bar of bars">
     <ng-template mat-tab-label>
          <div [ngClass]="...your conditions">
            bar.heading
          </div>
      </ng-template>
       ...
       ...
  </mat-tab>
```

Comment: There is a confusion. IsActive is not 'is the tab active', but a property of a domain object, which is, by coincidence, called IsActive.

The active angular tab is not necessarily an object with IsActive = true and vice-versa

Comment: Your nested div with a custom class works for some kinds of css (e.g. colors, font-face) but you cannot style the specific mat-tab-label of that tab (e.g. max-width, margins).  I'm trying to put an icon in one or more of the the last tabs and have the 'icon tabs' have exactly 50px width.  Can't seem to do that with this approach.

Answer (score -1):

Alternatively you can use ::ng-deep, google it.